# How to increment value in hashmap when id occurs inside a loop?

Tags: c#

I have a known number of `ids` (stored in var `count`), and I want to get the number of occurences each id has when looping inside a process:

```
//init hashtable
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
   hashtable.Add(i, 0);
}

for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
   //some process to get and id
   // for instance
   // 14
   // 17 
   // 17
   // 3
   // how to search i id and increment value?
}
```

So result would be

```
Hash(14,1)
Hash(17,2)
Hash(3,1)
```

How do I search and update the hashtable value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the value and set it to the new value using the [item indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item(v=vs.110).aspx). The HashTable class is not strongly-typed, so you have to explicitly cast it back to an int.

```
for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
    var id = ...get id...;
    hashtable[id] = ((int)hashtable[id]) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `Dictionary<int,int>` instead where each dictionary entry key maps to the number of the times the value occurs.

```
var idMap = new Dictionary<int,int>();
for (int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
   if(idMap.ContainsKey(id))
   {
     idMap[id] = idMap[id]+1;
   }
   else
   {
     idMap[i] = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for efficiency here like 10 Billion records, will Dictionary behaves better than hashmap?

Comment: That won't fit into memory either way - you need a different way to solve your problem then.

Comment: Ok, and in terms of speed? would you still suggest using Dictionary?

Comment: it would be faster since you don't have casting to and from `object` - nobody uses the pre-generic .NET 1.1 types anymore - any reason for that?